# ValueAnimator memory issue

Tags: android, objectanimator

I'm using `ValueAnimator` of float values.

```
ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(-1, 1);
anim.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            float f = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        }
    });
```

Here is the issue - memory allocation tracker detected that on each call of `getAnimatedValue()` a new `Float` object is created. I'm using `ValueAnimator` in `INFINITE` repeat mode and creating new objects constantly is kind of a problem. Is there any way to prevent creating new object all the time?

P.S.: I know that such kind of memory leak is not critical at all, just interested in optimization.

Comment: where that Float is created? by who? how do you construct your `ValueAnimator` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to prevent creating new `Float` objects on each time `onAnimationUpdate()` method is invoked. In my case it looks like:

```
@Override
public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
    float t = 2f * animation.getAnimatedFraction() - 1f;
}
```